# Wamp server is not working although it is showing green icon

Tags: php, wampserver

I have been developing a `php` project and the `wamp` server was seems 
    working fine but suddenly it stops working and i don't know what to do
    because when i check its status it says server online and green icon is also
    showing but it just does not work whenever i run `.php` files, Mr. browser 
    just write it down as i did in notepad++ but before some days it was      working 
    fine, please help me I'm kinda stuck?

I also want to mention that in the mean while I installed tomcat server for some other work is it anything to do with fault because i'm pretty sure both operating on differnet port numbers

Comment: What is the error message? You should read the error log file of apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<?php instead of <?`or left click wamp > php > settings > short_open_tags

and make sure you are running your scripts through localhost and not just opening the php file in the browser

[Read More about wamp problem](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,81661,83058)

Comment: thnks for the link it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you're definitely viewing the script through your MAMP setup (if your URL bar starts with `http://` instead of `file://`) and it is showing the *contents* of the PHP file instead of executing the script, it sounds like Apache is running fine, but PHP-FPM is the issue or a misconfiguration between the two. Apache should detect it is a PHP script and ship it to the PHP-FPM process, accept a response then ship it to your browser.

I would recommend checking PHP-FPM logs first. All logs are in `MAMP/logs` - scroll to the bottom of each one for latest entries. Ensure the service is running as expected and logging hits when Apache serves a `.php` file. PHP-FPM may be using a socket file (which can hit permission problems) or on a network port (which can be in use/require admin privileges/etc). Otherwise check your config files, or re-install MAMP for fresh config files.

If Apache cannot start, common reasons are;

- The port is in use by another application
- The port is a low number and you do not have administrator privileges to use that port
- Switching from wired to wireless / switching network adapters / changing hostname, etc
- Apache is already running, or Apache *thinks* it is

Comment: no, i'm running the project locally and the url starting with file://

Answer (score 0):

You must sign out from Skype it'll occupied the port of Apache or you should turn down the server and then restart you pc and turn it on. It will work fine.

Comment: I don't have skype :)